# Using a matrix as a index to identify instances of characters in another - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have three matrices specifying an index (`ind`), the type of datapoint (`type` - character list) and the value of this datapoint (`pos`).

```
ind=
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
3
3

type = 
A
A
B
A
C
B
C
B
A
B
C

pos = 

52150
109583
131411
193221
69719
203747
217250
269560
306121
324084
333170
```

**Problem 1**: What is the best way to tally the instances of each type within the confines of the index? e.g. there are 3A's and 1B for index = 1. The following partially works but cuts off any datapoint occurring at the boundary of different indices:

```
Count(:,1) = accumarray(ind(intersect([strfind(type,'A')],find(~diff(ind)))),1);
```

**Problem 2**: How could I use the same index to determine the `diff` between the datapoints for specific `type` pairs? e.g. if I wanted to find the difference between A-A pairs, ind = 1 would give the answer 109583-52150 = 57433 and 193221-109583 = 83,638. Within ind = 2 it would then give no answer as there is only 1 A in this index. These are always calculated sequentially down the matrix - one letter with it's next valid letter.

I will sometimes need to find more than one pair e.g. A-B and B-A distances - skipping any C's.

**EDIT**: When the pairs are mixed i.e. A-B/B-A, diff is calculated between the current letter and whatever is the next matching letter - sequentially down the matrix.

For ind = 1 the results would be:

```
109583-52150 = 57433 (A2-A1)
131411-109583 = 21,828 (B1-A2)
193221-131411 = 61,810 (A3-B1)
```

If a C was present and this was not being searched for it, it would simply be ignored and the value of the next matching point used for `diff`.

Comment: It seems `pos` has 12 elements, is that correct?

Comment: Sorry - fixed. It should contain 11 elements - all three matrices should be the same length.

Comment: The edit does not make sense. Wouldn't it be something like: A2-A1, B1-A2, A3-B1?

Comment: Yes - I was not showing the subtraction being performed - just identifying which type pairs are being used. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the occurances you could use

```
[v, c] = unique(type(ind==x));
```

That gives you each element in `type` (specified by `ind` ofc) and in `c` you have the number of occurances. (did I get the question right here?)

The second question I don't understand. How would a A-B diff look like if you have 4A's and 1B's?
In general, you can use the `&`-Operator to combine different restictions, e.g.

```
pos((ind==1)&(type=='A'))
ans =
       52150
      109583
      193221
diff(pos((ind==1)&(type=='A')))
ans = 
       57433
       83638
```

If you need to add several `type`'s, you can simply add them by using this

```
pos((ind==1)&((type=='A')|(type=='B')))
ans =
       52150
      109583
      131411
      193221
diff(pos((ind==1)&((type=='A')|(type=='B'))))
ans =
       57433
       21828
       61810
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the OP with some further details on how the system would handle different pairs.

Comment: Second part is perfect! I'm not too sure how to use `[v, c] = unique(type(ind==x));` - i'm looking for it to create a column per type (so in this case - 3 columns for A/B/C) and then a row (equal to the number of different indexes) in each specifying how many of each letter is present in each index. I may be missing something!

Comment: You can make a for loop and loop through all x=[1, 2, 3...] to create the column per type.